# Why this map function does not give traits' simple names

Tags: scala, traits

I try to get names of all trait a class extends using `getInterfaces` which returns an array of trait's names. When I manually access each member of the array, the method `getName` returns simple names like this

```
trait A
trait B

class C() extends A, B

val c = C()
val arr = c.getClass.getInterfaces
arr(0).getName // : String = A
arr(1).getName // : String = B
```

However, when I use `map` function on `arr`. The resulting array contains a cryptic version of trait's names

```
arr.map(t => t.getName) // : Array[String] = Array(repl$.rs$line$1$A, repl$.rs$line$2$B)
```

The goal of this question is not about how to get the resulting array that contains simple names (for that purpose, I can just use `arr.map(t => t.getSimpleName)`.) What I'm curious about is that why accessing array manually and using a `map` do not yield a compatible result. Am I wrong to think that both ways are equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you run things in Scala REPL or Ammonite.

When you define:

```
trait A
trait B

class C() extends A, B
```

classes `A`, `B` and `C` aren't defined in top level of root package. REPL creates some isolated environment, compiles the code and loads the results into some inner "anonymous" namespace.

Except this is not true. Where this bytecode was created is reflected in class name. So apparently there was something similar (not necessarily identical) to

```
// repl$ suggest object
object repl {

  // .rs sound like nested object(?)
  object rs {
   
    // $line sounds like nested class
    class line { /* ... */ }
  
    // $line$1 sounds like the first anonymous instance of line
    new line { trait A }
    // import from `above

    // $line$2 sounds like the second anonymous instance of line
    new line { trait B }
    // import from above
    //...
  }
}
```

which was made because of how scoping works in REPL: new line creates a new scope with previous definitions seen and new added (possibly overshadowing some old definition). This could be achieved by creating a new piece of code as code of new anonymous class, compiling it, reading into classpath, instantiating and importing its content. Byt putting each new line into separate class REPL is able to compile and run things in steps, without waiting for you to tell it that the script is completed and closed.

When you are accessing class names with runtime reflection you are seeing the artifacts of how things are being evaluated. One path might go trough REPLs prettifiers which hide such things, while the other bypass them so you see the raw value as JVM sees it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you do me a favor by recommending how to learn more about REPLs prettifiers?

Comment: Not really. The idea is that REPL want to do something to hide its internals, so it processes the text before outputting it to you. And it sometimes misses something, because it can only pattern-match limited number of formats and any slight change to it would escape it. E.g. Ammonite tries to find a structure in the output and color parenthesis, primitive names, etc, and doesn't bother with `classOf[A].getName` returning `"ammonite.$sess.cmd7$A"`. Scala REPL tries to hide it with (probably) regexpes, so you would get `"A"`.

Comment: But modify it a bit e.g. with `classOf[A].getName.split("").map(" " + _).mkString` and you'll get `" $ l i n e 3 . $ r e a d $ $ i w $ A"` which shows what it attempted to hide.

Comment: Interestingly, when I filter out the space from your string I've got back a simple name: `classOf[A].getName.split("").map(" " + _).mkString.filter(c => c != ' ')` print `val res15: String = A`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with `map` rather with `Array`, especially its `toString` method *(which is one among the many reasons for not using `Array`)*.

Actually, in this case it is even worse since the REPL does some weird things to try to pretty-print `Arrays` which in this case didn't work well *(and, IMHO, just add to the confusion)*

You can fix this problem calling `mkString` directly like:

```scala
val arr = c.getClass.getInterfaces
val result = arr.map(t => t.getName)
val text = result.mkString("[", ", ", "]")
println(text)
```

However, I would rather suggest just not using `Array` at all, instead convert it to a proper collection *(e.g. `List`)* as soon as possible like:

```scala
val interfaces = c.getClass.getInterfaces.toList
interfaces .map(t => t.getName)
```

---

> **Note**: About the other reasons for not using `Arrays`
>
> - They are mutable.
> - Thet are invariant.
> - They are not part of the collections hierarchy thus you can't use them on generic methods *(well, you actually can but that requires more tricks)*.
> - Their `equals` is by reference instead of by value.